# Is it mandatory to use sessions in Django to stop one user's information being displayed to another?

Tags: django

Hi I'm very new at Django and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have created an application using Django where I have a form accepting information using the POST method. In views.py I then get the information I want and store it in a variable to be displayed back to the page.

However, when I deployed this to heroku, I noticed anyone who accessed the webpage would enter their name and their name would be visible to everyone. I didn't store it in a database, it's only stored in a variable. How do I make it so that all user entered by a user stays on only their page when they access it? Do I need to use sessions?

Comment: Briefly: using global variables to store state in a web application is never a good idea; and, yes, using sessions or models is probably the right way to do what you want.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thank you for your reply, your hint about global variables is what has saved me! I was only testing things out and therefore was using global variables and no classes, so no instances were made. Now with classes and instances I don't run into this issue. Rookie mistake, thanks!